# Real Analysis Royden Third Edition, Chapter $4$ Proposition $3$

Tags: real-analysis

Reading over Proposition $3$ of Chapter $4$ several times, I still can't understand a couple of lines in the last paragraph of the proof.

**3. Proposition:** *Let $f$ be defined and bounded on a measurable set $E$ with $mE$ finite. In order that*

$$\underset{f\leq \psi}{\text{inf}} \int_E \psi(x) dx = \underset{f\geq \varphi}{\text{sup}} \int_E \varphi(x) dx$$

*for all simple functions $\varphi$ and $\psi$, it is necessary and sufficient that $f$ be measurable.*

I'm having trouble with the *necessary* part of the proof:

*Suppose now that*

$$\underset{f\leq \psi}{\text{inf}} \int_E \psi(x) dx = \underset{f\geq \varphi}{\text{sup}} \int_E \varphi(x) dx$$

*Then, given $n$, there are simple functions $\varphi_n$ and $\psi_n$ such that $\varphi_n(x) \leq f(x) \leq \psi_n(x)$ and*

$$\int_E \psi_n(x) dx - \int_E \varphi_n(x) dx<\frac{1}{n}.$$

*Then the functions* $$\psi^* = \text{inf}\: \psi_n$$

$and$ $$\varphi^* = \text{sup}\: \varphi_n$$ *are measurable by Theorem 3.20, and*

$$\varphi^*(x) \leq f(x) \leq \psi^*(x)$$

*Now the set $\Delta= \{x:\varphi^*(x) < \psi^*(x) \}$ is the union of the sets $\Delta_v = \left\{x:\varphi^*(x)<\psi^*(x)-\frac{1}{v}\right\}$*

*But each $\Delta_v$ is contained in the set* $\{x: \varphi_n(x)<\psi_n(x)-1/v\}$, **and this latter set has measure less than $v/n$.**

I get the build up, but I can't figure out why? Why would the set have measure less than $v/n$? I’ve stared at the page and thought about the problem for a lot of time, but I don’t even know how to start.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $$\int_E\big[ \psi_n(x) - \varphi_n(x)\big] dx<\frac{1}{n}.$$
Which implies $$\int_{\Delta_v}\big[ \psi_n(x) - \varphi_n(x)\big] dx<\frac{1}{n}.$$
And since the integrand is bounded below by $\frac{1}{v}$, the integral is bounded below by $\frac{m(\Delta_v)}{v}$

Comment: Thank you for responding! But how can one bring the $v$ over safely to get less than $v/n$?

Comment: It's not explicitly stated but $v$ must be a positive number.

Comment: I’ve tried to give this as much thought as possible before responding, essentially because $v\geq 1$ the above integral is $\leq 1/n \leq v/n$? I still can’t see why it would need to be written this way? Couldn’t the author simply of stuck with $1/n$? Also, I don’t see how the author is able to switch from integral to measurement of a set… btw I’m not sure if u noticed, but there is an extra $dx$ in the integrands of your integrals

Comment: Cont’d: Is it because one essentially gets $0\leq \frac{m\Delta_v}{v} \leq \int_E [\psi_n(x) -\varphi_n(x)] dx <\frac{1}{n}$ from the inequalities you’ve provided? And more importantly $0\leq \frac{m\Delta_v}{v} <\frac{1}{n} \Rightarrow 0\leq m\Delta_v <\frac{v}{n}$?

Comment: @nolemonnomelon Yes, that's the idea.